# CSS width with IE7: inline-block not working even after hacks

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to display a list of images with text on my webpage. But in IE7, it is displaying each image below the other and not next to other. Looks like it is because of lack of support of inline-block. I read some articles and added some things to my CSS, but still it is not working.

He is the HTML:

```
 <div id="image_example">
            <div class="accept">
                <h4>Acceptable</h4>
                <img width="84" height="150" src="some-image" alt="accept">
            </div>


            <div class="unaccept">
                <h4>Unacceptable</h4>
                <img width="112" height="150" src="some-image"">
            </div>


            <div class="unaccept">
                <h4>Unacceptable</h4>
                <img width="215" height="150" src="some-image">
            </div>


            <divclass="unaccept">
                <h4>Unacceptable</h4>
                <img width="165" height="150" alt="unaccept" src="some-image"">
            </div>

    </div>
```

My CSS looks like this::

```
.unaccept, .accept{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0.75em;
  zoom:1;//Added after reading other posts
  *display:inline; //Added after reading other posts
 }
```

I added the last two lines after reading a lot of articles/ pages about this problem. But still it is not working.

I tried adding:
     *width:173px to the class accept, but then it is breaking when the image width is more, if I increase the width width of all accept classes(even where the image width is less is getting increased, so the page does not look good again).

Can someone please help me out? All I want is to display these images next to each other with their default widths.

Comment: maybe you can use a table instead. that works fine in ie7.

Comment: @KeesSonnema Oh no, not tables!...

Comment: Why you use span for the last one instead of div ?

Comment: It was just a try in my firebug console, actual code has div. WIll edit. Thanks.

Comment: Forget IE7, I cant even make a fiddle using IE7 developer tools

Comment: Me neither, its the worst thing which could have happened to mankind..

Comment: Lol.. I would be rofling at that usually.. But I am way too depressed..

Comment: @Mr.Alien: The problem is not developers with old browsers, it's that developers have to develop for users with old browsers. Microsoft is working with getting rid of IE6 to start with... http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Answer (score 0):

IE7 only supports `inline-block` on elements that are inline by default.

Use `float: left;` instead, that works with following the standards, without any IE hacks:

```
.image_example { overflow: hidden; }

.unaccept, .accept {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0.75em;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/xCREN/

Comment: @Mr.Alien: That's what the `overflow` is doing.

Comment: Ah, I already tried that, and tried again, it still does not work in IE. I still see images in the next line.

Comment: BTw, the jsfiddle doesn't even load in IE7 :(

Comment: @user735574: The jsfiddle interface doesn't work in older IE, but you can right click in the view frame, get the properties and copy the URL, then browse to that page in IE7 (or a separate window in IE where you set the document mode to IE7). Here is the URL for the fiddle above: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Guffa/xCREN/show/

Comment: @user735574: In what way doesn't it work? When I test it I get exactly the same behaviour in IE7 as in newer browsers.

Comment: I tried putting the CSS you mentioned in my app, and it was still displaying images above and below instead of displaying it next to each other.

Comment: However I fixed the problem by applying inline width on the parent div(with class accept), depending on the image width..